# What does "missing-wedge corrected" mean?

Tags: image-processing

> For identification of macromolecular complexes in cryoelectron tomo- 
>   grams covering cytoplasmic regions, we used a combination of
>   subtomogram  averaging and classification. In a first step, the cross
>   correlation function  between two times binned tomograms and a 25 nm
>   spherical template  was computed. From the corresponding correlation
>   peaks subvolumes  (24 × 24 × 24 voxels) were extracted and classified
>   into 12 classes via a **missing-wedge corrected multi reference
>   classification procedure**, using the    initial template with different
>   representations of Gaussian noise added as    starting references.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer myself :)

In transmission electron microscopy one obtains a 3D image by tilting the sample stage. Usually it's 180°-x and x is called "missing wedge".

Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_electron_microscopy#Three-dimensional_imaging